# PyCharm and SCSS - Is there a way to compile SCSS into CSS from within the IDE?

Tags: sass, pycharm

Is there a way to compile SCSS into CSS from within the IDE? How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature was added in PyCharm 2.7.2 (currently [available in EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/PYH/JetBrains+PyCharm+Preview)).

See `File` | `Settings` | `Plugins` **File Watchers**:

[image: compile SCSS]

- [Blog post about this feature](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/file-watchers-in-webstormphpstorm-6-a-k-a-background-tasks/)

Comment: @dabadaba you can set up an External Tool and assign a hotkey to it.